# My USB D+ and D- signals have what looks like a clock signal embedded onto it. The chip is a ISP1362

Tags: usb, usb-host, usb-hub

I am trying to load a firmware up-rev to a device with a USB stick. It doesn't see the stick. My USB D+ and D- signals have what looks like a clock signal embedded onto them. The chip is an ISP1362 USB OTG controller see www.farnell.com/datasheets/1668574.pdf

I have not found any components that seem to be bad.
To see a picture of the D+ incoming signal that looks like it has the clock signal mixed into it, copy and paste the following into a separate window.

[image]

The scope is set at .5 usec/div.

[image: Schematic]
Pin 48 is wrong on the schematic, it is pulled low.
Here are the readings I measured: on ISP1362.

Pin
20 3v
21 3v
22 3v
28 3v
29 3v
23 0v
59 0v
60 3v
48 0v
45 3v
30 3v
41 5v
46 signal shown when USB first inserted, otherwise 0v
47 inverted signal shown when USB first inserted, otherwise 3v
33 0v
34 0v
61 3v
62 3v
56 5v
4, 14, 26, 40, 52, 56   3v
1, 9, 19, 27, 57, 51     0v

Any guess as to what the problem might be?

Comment: It looks noisy, that's it.

Comment: The image is at http://imgur.com/a/U0sil

Comment: More info to come later

Comment: Shown is one complete cycle, if this was just noise it would be random but this is constant and it matches the output of the clock at 3rd and 6th division

Comment: Noise is not necessarily random. It can be a cross-talk with some other signal (like clock). And the D signal is differential, so you should look at the difference between D+ and D-, not on one of them.

Comment: "More info to come later" is not a way to post questions that you actually want answers to. And I do hope you mean _more_ information, because we know hardly anything here.

Comment: Show us your schematic and layout.

Comment: What's the scope bandwidth?

Comment: Apart from the low scope bandwidth it looks normal to me. Does your scope have dual trace? If so then show us both D+ and D- signals together. Use 10x probes and make sure they are properly adjusted for flat square wave response. Here's an example of what you might see:- http://kevinpt.github.io/ripyl/_images/usb_data_hs_example.png

Answer (score 2):

If it is 0.5 us/division, I think it's just a  bandwidth problem.

A full speed device will have 12Mbps. In your image, in one division I see up to 6 periods, which means exactly 12 MHz (83 ns per bit). That signal is just normal.

Answer (score 1):

Could be these things:
1) The [scope does not have enough bandwidth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227946/what-frequency-should-an-oscilloscope-be-rated-at-to-measure-usb-signals) to capture the signal, get a better scope. (or turn up the time resolution if possible).  Make sure the probes can handle the bandwith also
2) The scope impedance is too high. Make sure the probe is clipped to the shortest possible distance between the signal that your monitoring and the nearest ground on the IC.